# Converting pdf ebooks that has java code to kindle format

Tags: pdf, kindle, calibre

I tried kindle's username@free.kindle.com, calibre, mobipocket creator and none of them work with the book that has java/html css code in it. Am I the only one who is facing this situation or are there any one who had problem trouble converting a pdf that has code samples in the book to kindle and still preserve the code formatting. Any suggestions please?

Comment: see way 2, may be help

Answer (score 1):

On this site with a link something. To get to a place with free components to try much. Pay package is worth $ 2000-4000 + depending on the type of license. See if you fit any of that.

[Aspose Files Free](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/default.aspx)

[Aspose.Total for Java](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/72/java-components/aspose.total-for-java/entry88905.aspx)

Aspose.Total for Java includes the following libraries:

1. Aspose.Words for Java 13.3.0 (4/2/2013 7:47:49 PM)
2. Aspose.OCR for Java 1.1.0 (4/2/2013 12:12:00 PM)
3. Aspose.Slides for Java 7.2.0 (4/1/2013 1:43:26 PM)
4. Aspose.Email for Java 2.8.0 (3/28/2013 11:59:48 PM)
5. Aspose.Cells for Java 7.4.2 (3/25/2013 5:52:14 AM)
6. Aspose.Pdf.Kit for Java 4.5.0 (2/21/2013 10:02:34 AM)
7. Aspose.Imaging for Java 1.7.0 (2/4/2013 12:25:31 AM)
8. Aspose.BarCode for Java 5.3.0 (2/4/2013 12:00:13 AM)
9. Aspose.Pdf for Java 3.3.0 (10/11/2012 9:54:29 AM)
10. Aspose.Metafiles for Java 1.8.0 (8/9/2012 11:55:47 AM)

[How-to Convert a Document to EPUB](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsjava/How-to+Convert+a+Document+to+EPUB)

[Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/java/word-component.aspx)

way 2:

Pdf: [The verbments package: Pretty printing source code in LaTeX*](http://www.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/verbments/verbments.pdf)

[LaTeX to PDF](http://mintaka.sdsu.edu/GF/bibliog/latex/LaTeXtoPDF.html)

Comment: I think u misunderstood the question, I am looking for a free converter that preserves the code samples in the text book yet generate a kindle version

Comment: @user78338 - A free tool might not exist.  This is an acceptable answer.

Comment: @user78338 top link to free version. But your may create xslt transformation rule and zip files to create e-book.